# [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content

Tags: vuejs2

[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside

, or missing . Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.

```
 <template lang="pug">
    div
      header
       h1 project news line
       nav
        nuxt-link(to='/') home
        nuxt-link(to='/about') about 
        nuxt-link(to='/contacts') call me
      .wrapper
       form(@submit="postMesseage")
        section.container
         md-input-container
          label With label
          md-input(placeholder='Head',  v-model="name", type='text', )

          button(type="submit") add news
         .quill-editor(:content='content', @change='onEditorChange($event)', @blur='onEditorBlur($event)', @focus='onEditorFocus($event)', @ready='onEditorReady($event)', v-quill:myquilleditor='editorOption', v-model="newMessage")

       section#message(v-for='(message, index) in messages')

         button( @click="deleteRow(index)" v-bind:id="message._id") удалить
         nuxt-link(:to="{ path: '/edite/'+message._id,  params: { id: message._id } }") 
          button Редактировать
         h2 
          nuxt-link(:to="{ path: '/news/'+message._id,  params: { id: message._id } }" ) {{ message.name }}

           div(v-html="message.content") {{ message.content }}




    </template>
```

how fix it ? not understand :( help please